# Using vectors for performance improvement in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell

I'm very new to Haskell, and I have a question about what performance improvements can be had by using impure (mutable) data structures. I'm trying to piece together a few different things I've heard, so please bear with me if my terminology is not entirely correct, or if there are some small errors.

To make this concrete, consider the quicksort algorithm (taken from the Haskell wiki).

```
quicksort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
quicksort []     = []
quicksort (p:xs) = (quicksort lesser) ++ [p] ++ (quicksort greater)
    where
        lesser  = filter (< p) xs
        greater = filter (>= p) xs
```

This is not "true quicksort." A "true" quicksort algorithm is in-place, and this is not. This is very memory inefficient.

On the other hand, it is possible to use vectors in Haskell to implement an in-place quicksort. An example is given in [this stackoverflow answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7833043/1525027)

How much faster is the second algorithm than the first? Big O notation doesn't help here, because the performance improvement is going to be from using memory more efficiently, not having a better algorithm (right?). I tired to construct some test cases on my own, but I had difficult getting things running.

An ideal answer would give some idea of what makes the in-place Haskell algorithm faster theoretically, and an example comparison of running times on some test data set.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's nothing better than a test, right? And the results are not unsurprising: for lists of random integers in range `[0 .. 1000000]`,

```
list size: 200000         ghc              -O2     -fllvm  -fllvm-O2
────────                   ────────   ────────   ────────   ────────
Data.List.sort            0.878969s  0.883219s  0.878106s  0.888758s
Naïve.quicksort           0.711305s  0.870647s  0.845508s  0.919925s
UArray_IO.quicksort       9.317783s  1.919583s  9.390687s  1.945072s
Vector_Mutable.quicksort   1.48142s  0.823004s  1.526661s  0.806837s
```

Here, `Data.List.sort` is just what it is, `Naïve.quicksort` is the algorithm you quoted, `UArray_IO.quicksort` and `Vector_Mutable.quicksort` are taken from the question you linked to: [klapaucius'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7833043/745903) and [Dan Burton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7719971/745903) ***which turn out to be very suboptimal performance-wise, see what better [Daniel Fischer could do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11485331/745903)***, both wrapped so as to accept lists (not sure if I got this quite right):

```
quicksort :: [Int] -> [Int]
quicksort l = unsafePerformIO $ do
  let bounds = (0, length l)
  arr <- newListArray bounds l :: IO (IOUArray Int Int)
  uncurry (qsort arr) bounds
  getElems arr
```

and

```
quicksort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
quicksort = toList . iqsort . fromList
```

respectively.

As you can see, the naïve algorithm is not far behind the mutable solution with `Data.Vector` in terms of speed for sorting a list of random-generated integers, and the `IOUArray` is actually *much worse*. Test was carried out on an Intel i5 laptop running Ubuntu 11.10 x86-64.

---

*The following doesn't really make much sense considering that ɢᴏᴏᴅ mutable implementations are, after all, still well ahead of all those compared here.*

Note that this does not mean that a nice list-based program can always keep up with its mutably-implemented equivalents, but GHC sure does a great job at bringing the performance close. Also, it depends of course on the data: these are the times when the random-generated lists to sort contain values in between 0 and 1000 rather than 0 an 1000000 as above, i.e. with many duplicates:

```
list size: 200000         ghc               -O2      -fllvm  -fllvm-O2
────────                    ────────   ────────    ────────   ────────
Data.List.sort             0.864176s  0.882574s   0.850807s  0.857957s
Naïve.quicksort            1.475362s  1.526076s   1.475557s  1.456759s
UArray_IO.quicksort       24.405938s  5.255001s  23.561911s  5.207535s
Vector_Mutable.quicksort   3.449168s  1.125788s   3.202925s  1.117741s
```

Not to speak of pre-sorted arrays.

What's quite interesting, (becomes only apparent with really large sizes, which require rtsopts to increase the stack capacity), is how both mutable implementations become significantly *slower* with `-fllvm -O2`:

```
list size: 3⋅10⁶        ghc      -O1   -fllvm-O1         -O2   -fllvm-O2
────────                    ────────    ────────    ────────    ────────
Data.List.sort            23.897897s  24.138117s  23.708218s  23.631968s
Naïve.quicksort           17.068644s  19.547817s  17.640389s  18.113622s
UArray_IO.quicksort       35.634132s  38.348955s  37.177606s  49.190503s
Vector_Mutable.quicksort  17.286982s  17.251068s  17.361247s  36.840698s
```

It seems kind of logical to me that the immutable implementations fare better on llvm (doesn't it do everything immutably on some level?), though I don't understand why this only becomes apparent as a slowdown to the mutable versions at high optimisation and large data sizes.

---

### Testing program:

```
$ cat QSortPerform.hs
module Main where

import qualified Data.List(sort)
import qualified Naïve
import qualified UArray_IO
import qualified Vector_Mutable

import Control.Monad
import System.Random
import System.Environment

sortAlgos :: [ (String, [Int]->[Int]) ]
sortAlgos = [ ("Data.List.sort", Data.List.sort)
            , ("Naïve.quicksort", Naïve.quicksort)
            , ("UArray_IO.quicksort", UArray_IO.quicksort)
            , ("Vector_Mutable.quicksort", Vector_Mutable.quicksort) ]

main = do
   args <- getArgs
   when (length args /= 2) $ error "Need 2 arguments"

   let simSize = read $ args!!1
   randArray <- fmap (take simSize . randomRs(0,1000000)) getStdGen

   let sorted = case filter ((== args!!0) . fst) sortAlgos of
        [(_, algo)] -> algo randArray
        _ -> error $ "Argument must be one of " 
                        ++ show (map fst sortAlgos)

   putStr "First element:  "; print $ sorted!!0
   putStr "Middle element: "; print $ sorted!!(simSize`div`2)
   putStr "Last element:   "; print $ sorted!!(simSize-1)
```

which takes the algorithm name and array size on command-line. Runtime comparison was done with this program:

```
$ cat PerformCompare.hs
module Main where

import System.Process
import System.Exit
import System.Environment
import Data.Time.Clock
import Data.List
import Control.Monad
import Text.PrettyPrint.Boxes

compiler = "ghc"
testProgram = "./QSortPerform"
flagOpts = [[], ["-O2"], ["-fllvm"], ["-fllvm","-O2"]]
algos = ["Data.List.sort","Naïve.quicksort","UArray_IO.quicksort","Vector_Mutable.quicksort"]


main = do
   args <- getArgs
   let testSize = case args of
         [numb] -> read numb
         _      -> 200000

   results <- forM flagOpts $ \flags -> do

      compilerExitC <- verboseSystem
              compiler $ testProgram : "-fforce-recomp" : flags
      when (compilerExitC /= ExitSuccess) .
         error $ "Compiler error \"" ++ show compilerExitC ++"\""

      algoCompare <- forM algos $ \algo -> do
         startTime <- getCurrentTime
         exitC <- verboseSystem testProgram [algo, show testSize]
         endTime <- getCurrentTime
         when (exitC /= ExitSuccess) .
            error $ "Program error \"" ++ show exitC ++"\""
         return . text . show $ diffUTCTime endTime startTime

      return . vcat right $ text(concat flags)
                          : text("────────")
                          : algoCompare

   let table = hsep 2 bottom
         $ vcat left (map text $ ("list size: "++show testSize)
                               : "────────"
                               : algos                          )
         : results

   printBox table



verboseSystem :: String -> [String] -> IO ExitCode
verboseSystem cmd args = do
   putStrLn . unwords $ cmd : args
   rawSystem cmd args
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. I suspect the array implementation can be made much better. The answerer admits to directly porting code from Wikipedia, so it's probably not as efficient as it could be.

Comment: I think so too, this is really just "let's port this C code to Haskell changing as little as possible", which can't be expected to be much good. However, the `Data.Array`s are generally said to be slower than `Vector`, so I doubt it could actually get much better than that. — Somewhere in the future, Data Parallel Haskell's `[: :]` will probably beat them all, including Fortran arrays...

Comment: @Potato Indeed, one can make much, much better array versions. And much much better vector versions. Both should beat the list versions by a huge margin.

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-algorithms has a number of implementations; I'd like to see _those_ benchmarked.

Comment: `vector-algorithms` has an elaborate bench system http://code.haskell.org/~dolio/vector-algorithms/bench/

Comment: @LouisWasserman I've included a small benchmark of the other vector-algorithms algorithms in my answer. Nothing surprising.

Comment: Hrm, I wrote the UArray_IO implementation as sort of a proof of concept that you can write C in Haskell, so I wasn't necessarily going for speed, but I'm rather surprised at how abysmally that code performed in your tests. Anyone have any clues why the IOUArray code I wrote is so slow? Needs more INLINE pragmas, perhaps?

Answer (score 22):

> On the other hand, it is possible to use vectors in Haskell to implement an in-place quicksort.
>
> How much faster is the second algorithm than the first?

That depends on the implementation, of course. As can be seen below, for not too short lists, a decent in-place sort on a mutable vector or array is much faster than sorting lists, even if the time for the transformation from and to lists is included (*and that conversion makes up the bulk of the time*).

However, the list algorithms produce incremental output, while the array/vector algorithms don't produce any result before they have completed, therefore sorting lists can still be preferable.

I don't know exactly what the linked mutable array/vector algorithms did wrong. But they did something quite wrong.

For the mutable vector code, it seems that it used *boxed* vectors, and it was polymorphic, both can have significant performance impact, though the polymorphism shouldn't matter if the functions are `{-# INLINABLE #-}`.

For the `IOUArray` code, well, it looks fun, but slow. It uses an `IORef`, `readArray` and `writeArray` and has no obvious strictness. The abysmal times it takes aren't too surprising, then.

Using a more [direct translation](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Introduction/Direct_Translation) of the (monomorphic) C code using an `STUArray`, with a wrapper to make it work on lists¹,

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
module STUQuickSort (stuquick) where

import Data.Array.Base (unsafeRead, unsafeWrite)
import Data.Array.ST
import Control.Monad.ST

stuquick :: [Int] -> [Int]
stuquick [] = []
stuquick xs = runST (do
    let !len = length xs
    arr <- newListArray (0,len-1) xs
    myqsort arr 0 (len-1)
    -- Can't use getElems for large arrays, that overflows the stack, wth?
    let pick acc i
            | i < 0     = return acc
            | otherwise = do
                !v <- unsafeRead arr i
                pick (v:acc) (i-1)
    pick [] (len-1))

myqsort :: STUArray s Int Int -> Int -> Int -> ST s ()
myqsort a lo hi
   | lo < hi   = do
       let lscan p h i
               | i < h = do
                   v <- unsafeRead a i
                   if p < v then return i else lscan p h (i+1)
               | otherwise = return i
           rscan p l i
               | l < i = do
                   v <- unsafeRead a i
                   if v < p then return i else rscan p l (i-1)
               | otherwise = return i
           swap i j = do
               v <- unsafeRead a i
               unsafeRead a j >>= unsafeWrite a i
               unsafeWrite a j v
           sloop p l h
               | l < h = do
                   l1 <- lscan p h l
                   h1 <- rscan p l1 h
                   if (l1 < h1) then (swap l1 h1 >> sloop p l1 h1) else return l1
               | otherwise = return l
       piv <- unsafeRead a hi
       i <- sloop piv lo hi
       swap i hi
       myqsort a lo (i-1)
       myqsort a (i+1) hi
   | otherwise = return ()
```

and a wrapper around a good sort (Introsort, not quicksort) on unboxed vectors,

```
module VSort where

import Data.Vector.Algorithms.Intro
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U
import Control.Monad.ST

vsort :: [Int] -> [Int]
vsort xs = runST (do
    v <- U.unsafeThaw $ U.fromList xs
    sort v
    s <- U.unsafeFreeze v
    return $ U.toList s)
```

I get times more in line with the expectations (**Note:** For these timings, the random list has been `deepseq`ed before calling the sorting algorithm. Without that, the conversion to an `STUArray` would be much slower, since it would first evaluate a long list of thunks to determine the length. The `fromList` conversion of the [vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector) package doesn't suffer from this problem. Moving the `deepseq` to the conversion to `STUArray`, the other sorting [and conversion, in the vector case] algorithms take a little less time, so the difference between [vector-algorithms](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-algorithms)' introsort and the `STUArray` quicksort becomes a little larger.):

```
list size: 200000                    -O2     -fllvm  -fllvm-O2
────────             ────────   ────────   ────────   ────────
Data.List.sort      0.663501s  0.665482s  0.652461s  0.792005s
Naive.quicksort     0.587091s  0.577796s  0.585754s  0.667573s
STUArray.quicksort   1.58023s  0.142626s  1.597479s  0.156411s
VSort.vsort         0.820639s  0.139967s  0.888566s  0.143918s
```

The times without optimisation are expectedly bad for the `STUArray`. `unsafeRead` and `unsafeWrite` must be inlined to be fast. If not inlined, you get a dictionary lookup for each call. Thus for the large dataset, I omit the unoptimised ways:

```
list size: 3000000         -O2   -fllvm-O2
────────              ────────    ────────
Data.List.sort      16.728576s  16.442377s
Naive.quicksort     14.297534s  12.253071s
STUArray.quicksort   2.307203s   2.200807s
VSort.vsort          2.069749s   1.921943s
```

You can see that an inplace sort on a mutable unboxed array is **much** faster than a list-based sort if done correctly. <del>Whether the difference between the `STUArray` sort and the sort on the unboxed mutable vector is due to the different algorithm or whether vectors are indeed faster here, I don't know. Since I've never observed vectors to be faster² than `STUArray`s, I tend to believe the former.</del>
The difference between the `STUArray` quicksort and the introsort is in part due to the better conversion from and to lists that the [vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector) package offers, in part due to the different algorithms.

---

At [Louis Wasserman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481675/using-vectors-for-performance-improvement-in-haskell/11485331#comment15168576_11483226)'s suggestion, I have run a quick benchmark using the other sorting algorithms from the [vector-algorithms](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-algorithms) package, using a not-too-large dataset. The results aren't surprising, the good general-purpose algorithms heapsort, introsort and mergesort all do well, times near the quicksort on the unboxed mutable array (but of course, the quicksort would degrade to quadratic behaviour on almost sorted input, while these are guaranteed O(n*log n) worst case). The special-purpose sorting algorithms `AmericanFlag` and radix sort do badly, since the input doesn't fit well to their purpose (radix sort would do better on larger inputs with a larger range, as is, it does too many more passes than needed for the data). Insertion sort is by far the worst, due to its quadratic behaviour.

```
AmericanFlag:
list size: 300000         -O2  -fllvm-O2
────────             ────────   ────────
Data.List.sort      1.083845s  1.084699s
Naive.quicksort     0.981276s   1.05532s
STUArray.quicksort  0.218407s  0.215564s
VSort.vsort         2.566838s  2.618817s

Heap:
list size: 300000         -O2  -fllvm-O2
────────             ────────   ────────
Data.List.sort      1.084252s   1.07894s
Naive.quicksort     0.915984s  0.887354s
STUArray.quicksort  0.219786s  0.225748s
VSort.vsort         0.213507s   0.20152s

Insertion:
list size: 300000         -O2   -fllvm-O2
────────             ────────    ────────
Data.List.sort      1.168837s   1.066058s
Naive.quicksort     1.081806s   0.879439s
STUArray.quicksort  0.241958s   0.209631s
VSort.vsort         36.21295s  27.564993s

Intro:
list size: 300000         -O2  -fllvm-O2
────────             ────────   ────────
Data.List.sort       1.09189s  1.112415s
Naive.quicksort     0.891161s  0.989799s
STUArray.quicksort  0.236596s  0.227348s
VSort.vsort         0.221742s   0.20815s

Merge:
list size: 300000         -O2  -fllvm-O2
────────             ────────   ────────
Data.List.sort      1.087929s  1.074926s
Naive.quicksort     0.875477s  1.019984s
STUArray.quicksort  0.215551s  0.221301s
VSort.vsort         0.236661s  0.230287s

Radix:
list size: 300000         -O2  -fllvm-O2
────────             ────────   ────────
Data.List.sort      1.085658s  1.085726s
Naive.quicksort     1.002067s  0.900985s
STUArray.quicksort  0.217371s  0.228973s
VSort.vsort         1.958216s  1.970619s
```

Conclusion: Unless you have a specific reason not to, using one of the good general-purpose sorting algorithms from [vector-algorithms](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-algorithms), with a wrapper to convert from and to lists if necessary, is the recommended way to sort large lists. (These algorithms also work well with boxed vectors, in my measurements approximately 50% slower than unboxed.) For short lists, the overhead of the conversion would be so large that it doesn't pay.

---

Now, at @applicative's suggestion, a look at the sorting times for [vector-algorithms](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-algorithms)' introsort, a quicksort on unboxed vectors and an improved (shamelessly stealing the implementation of [`unstablePartition`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.9.1/doc/html/Data-Vector-Generic-Mutable.html#v:unstablePartition)) quicksort on `STUArray`s.

The improved `STUArray` quicksort:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
module NQuick (stuqsort) where


import Data.Array.Base (unsafeRead, unsafeWrite, getNumElements)
import Data.Array.ST
import Control.Monad.ST
import Control.Monad (when)

stuqsort :: STUArray s Int Int -> ST s ()
stuqsort arr = do
    n <- getNumElements arr
    when (n > 1) (myqsort arr 0 (n-1))

myqsort :: STUArray s Int Int -> Int -> Int -> ST s ()
myqsort a lo hi = do
    p <- unsafeRead a hi
    j <- unstablePartition (< p) lo hi a
    h <- unsafeRead a j
    unsafeWrite a j p
    unsafeWrite a hi h
    when (j > lo+1) (myqsort a lo (j-1))
    when (j+1 < hi) (myqsort a (j+1) hi)

unstablePartition :: (Int -> Bool) -> Int -> Int -> STUArray s Int Int -> ST s Int
{-# INLINE unstablePartition #-}
unstablePartition f !lf !rg !v = from_left lf rg
  where
    from_left i j
      | i == j    = return i
      | otherwise = do
                      x <- unsafeRead v i
                      if f x
                        then from_left (i+1) j
                        else from_right i (j-1)

    from_right i j
      | i == j    = return i
      | otherwise = do
                      x <- unsafeRead v j
                      if f x
                        then do
                               y <- unsafeRead v i
                               unsafeWrite v i x
                               unsafeWrite v j y
                               from_left (i+1) j
                        else from_right i (j-1)
```

The [vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector) quicksort:

```
module VectorQuick (vquicksort) where

import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as UM
import qualified Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable as GM
import Control.Monad.ST
import Control.Monad (when)

vquicksort :: UM.STVector s Int -> ST s ()
vquicksort uv = do
    let li = UM.length uv - 1
        ui = UM.unsafeSlice 0 li uv
    p <- UM.unsafeRead uv li
    j <- GM.unstablePartition (< p) ui
    h <- UM.unsafeRead uv j
    UM.unsafeWrite uv j p
    UM.unsafeWrite uv li h
    when (j > 1) (vquicksort (UM.unsafeSlice 0 j uv))
    when (j + 1 < li) (vquicksort (UM.unsafeSlice (j+1) (li-j) uv))
```

The timing code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
module Main (main) where

import System.Environment (getArgs)
import System.CPUTime
import System.Random
import Text.Printf

import Data.Array.Unboxed
import Data.Array.ST hiding (unsafeThaw)
import Data.Array.Unsafe (unsafeThaw)
import Data.Array.Base (unsafeAt, unsafeNewArray_, unsafeWrite)
import Control.Monad.ST
import Control.Monad

import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as UM

import NQuick
import VectorQuick
import qualified Data.Vector.Algorithms.Intro as I

nextR :: StdGen -> (Int, StdGen)
nextR = randomR (minBound, maxBound)

buildArray :: StdGen -> Int -> UArray Int Int
buildArray sg size = runSTUArray (do
    arr <- unsafeNewArray_ (0, size-1)
    let fill i g
            | i < size  = do
                let (r, g') = nextR g
                unsafeWrite arr i r
                fill (i+1) g'
            | otherwise = return arr
    fill 0 sg)

buildVector :: StdGen -> Int -> U.Vector Int
buildVector sg size = U.fromList $ take size (randoms sg)

time :: IO a -> IO ()
time action = do
    t0 <- getCPUTime
    action
    t1 <- getCPUTime
    let tm :: Double
        tm = fromInteger (t1 - t0) * 1e-9
    printf "%.3f ms\n" tm

stu :: UArray Int Int -> Int -> IO ()
stu ua sz = do
    let !sa = runSTUArray (do
                st <- unsafeThaw ua
                stuqsort st
                return st)
    forM_ [0, sz `quot` 2, sz-1] (print . (sa `unsafeAt`))

intro :: U.Vector Int -> Int -> IO ()
intro uv sz = do
    let !sv = runST (do
            st <- U.unsafeThaw uv
            I.sort st
            U.unsafeFreeze st)
    forM_ [0, sz `quot` 2, sz-1] (print . U.unsafeIndex sv)

vquick :: U.Vector Int -> Int -> IO ()
vquick uv sz = do
    let !sv = runST (do
            st <- U.unsafeThaw uv
            vquicksort st
            U.unsafeFreeze st)
    forM_ [0, sz `quot` 2, sz-1] (print . U.unsafeIndex sv)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    let !num = case args of
                 (a:_) -> read a
                 _ -> 1000000
    !sg <- getStdGen
    let !ar = buildArray sg num
        !vc = buildVector sg num
        !v2 = buildVector sg (foo num)
        algos = [ ("Intro", intro v2), ("STUArray", stu ar), ("Vquick", vquick vc) ]
    printf "Created data to be sorted, last elements %d %d %d\n" (ar ! (num-1)) (vc U.! (num-1)) (v2 U.! (num-1))
    forM_ algos $ \(name, act) -> do
        putStrLn name
        time (act num)

-- For the prevention of sharing
foo :: Int -> Int
foo n
    | n < 0 = -n
    | n > 0 = n
    | otherwise = 3
```

The results (times only):

```
$ ./timeSorts 3000000
Intro
587.911 ms
STUArray
402.939 ms
Vquick
414.936 ms
$ ./timeSorts 1000000
Intro
193.970 ms
STUArray
131.980 ms
Vquick
134.979 ms
```

The practically identical quicksorts on the `STUArray` and the unboxed vector take practically the same time, as expected. (The old quicksort implementation was about 15% slower than the introsort. Comparing to the times above, about 70-75% there was spent converting from/to lists.)

On the random input, the quicksorts perform significantly better than the introsort, but on almost-sorted input, their performance would degrade while introsort wouldn't.

---

¹ Making the code polymorphic with `STUArray`s is a pain at best, doing it with `IOUArray`s and having both the sorting and the wrapper `{-# INLINABLE #-}` produces the same performance with optimisations - without, the polymorphic code is significantly slower.

² Using the same algorithms, both were always equally fast within the precision of measurement when I compared (not very often).

Comment: I sure was a bit surprised, too, but then I thought oh well, the majority of work is done on small subarrays so we have lots of references to different places anyway so why should the list solution not compare, provided the memory allocations are fast? Good you corrected that.

Comment: Yeah, GHC can allocate blazingly fast. But not allocating is still faster.

Comment: Are you using a special flag for `STUArray.quicksort`? `VSort.vsort` (introsort) is systematically over twice as fast here, e.g. with -O2: `list size: 3000000 STUQuickSort.stuquick  5.617264s Vector.vsort 2.310885s`  Otherwise proportions are maintained, e.g. heapsort is slightly slower

Comment: @applicative No, the same flags as the other modules, `-O2` resp. `fllvm -O2`. What's your setup (GHC, OS, architecture)?

Comment: Oh it occurs to me one curiosity is I'm using a 2wk old ghc-head (on a somewhat dated macbook pro.)

Comment: @applicative Hmm, with 7.5.20120709, I get approximately the same timings for STUArray as with 7.4.2. I'd also be somewhat surprised if arrays were that badly broken in a head. However, I've no idea what could cause such a discrepancy.

Comment: Argh, I don't know.  It turns out my haskell-platform ghc-7.4.1 can compile it, and inevitably `list size: 300000 -O2 STUQuickSort.stuquick  0.555654s  VSort.vsort 0.258322s`  I must have introduced some grit somewhere.

Comment: A new theory, it may be os x: these are 64bit ghc's but 32 bit is said to be preferable on the Haskell Platform page -- I think carrying forward what is said here http://mtnviewmark.wordpress.com/2011/12/07/32-bits-less-is-more/ On the other hand I'd have thought these programs are using fairly similar ghc -machinery.

Comment: I guess installing a 32-bit GHC to test would be too much, @applicative? (Would be for me.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13893/discussion-between-applicative-and-daniel-fischer)

Comment: @applicative Ah, solved! I had added a `deepseq` to `QSortPerform.hs`, thinking that the stack overflow may have been caused by the `randomRs`. Without that, the `newListArray` first builds a long list of thunks to find out the length, and then evaluates the thunks to fill the array, which takes a while. The `fromList` of vector is cleverer (I don't know how it works, stack overflow trying to find the implementation). If I move the `deepseq` to `stuquick`, the vector sorts become a bit faster, so the difference is larger (much less than 2×, though).

Comment: It occurs to me we have an irrational starting point, namely: Which approach can implement the fastest [Int]->[Int] sort. If I make a vector of random ints with a dedicated library, then use introsort, it turns out introsort is about 10 times as fast as it seemed to be. The same actual sort is occurring, unless I'm getting something else wrong.

Comment: This fits with our experience that it is all about getting out of and into the list type. See http://hpaste.org/71535 I set the range of both to (maxBound ::Int,minBound ::Int). (Note here the disparity discussed above is smaller.) Something similar is surely true with the  STArray approach.

Comment: The new test module uses the dreaded `V.fromList`; omitting this detour makes introsort almost twice as fast http://hpaste.org/71647

Comment: @applicative That's because on line 45 you have a typo, `fill n g v (i+1)`, that should be `g'` there. As is, it sorts a sorted vector, of course that's faster. And since I don't time the creation, only the sorting, the way the vectors/arrays are created is unimportant.

Comment: Yes, that would speed things up!  My original thought was to avoid the freezing and unfreezing, but separated from the dimwitted typo, which let to my absurd account, this turns out to make only a minute difference, not too surprisingly.

Comment: @DanielFischer is it OK to copy your new improved `STUArray` quicksort code to the [haskellwiki page](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Introduction/Direct_Translation), stating it achieves ~1.7x (1.15*1.47) speedup vs. the old version that's there? Would it be hard to add the median-of-three pivot selection? (the [WP article on introsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort) seems to suggest that median-of-three is very good at preventing the slowdown on sorted inputs). Or randomized pivot selection?

Comment: @WillNess I have no objection, just make sure the vector package is credited for the better partitioning. However, my measurements are between 1.5× and 1.6× speedup, not 1.7×. Median-of-three is simple, and makes it blazingly fast for sorted arrays, but reverse-sorted are still quadratic [but about 4× as fast as picking the last as pivot]. Randomized pivot selection isn't hard either, as long as you're not picky with the pseudo-random algorithm (I got satisfactory results with very simple fast PRNGs).

Comment: I know this is old, but I get very bad performances with presorted vectors with a median of three implementation: http://pastebin.com/qxYduVGn (4 seconds for 100000 elements). What is happening?

Comment: @Simon I'm not going to analyse it deeply now, but, first of all, the code is not correct. You don't swap the pivot out of the way, so when you write `p` to index `j` and `h` to index `li`, you (not always, but often) erase one number, and duplicate another. Also, in your median selection, you construct a list, that means things have to be boxed, and the list manipulation is complicated and slow. You need to select and swap the pivot directly from the vector, no lists, no boxing.

Comment: @DanielFischer I have posted another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912348/fast-sorting-in-haskell)

Comment: It seems like this answer is comparing times instead of memory usage, which is what the question asked for. Am I misunderstanding what the numbers mean?

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin The question asks for times ("How much faster …", "comparison of running times on some test data set"). It also asks for an explanation why the in-place sorting is faster, which admittedly neither answer really goes into.