# Sort a linked list in O(n log n) with O(1) space complexity

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, linked-list, time-complexity

This is Sort List problem on LeetCode https://oj.leetcode.com/problems/sort-list/
I made a Java solution but it caused Time Limit Exceeded on an extremely long test case. And I couldn't find the bug in my code. Could anyone point out where the bug is? Many thanks.

```
class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next;
    ListNode(int x) {
        val = x;
        next = null;
    }
}

public class Solution {
    public ListNode sortList(ListNode head) {
        return this.sortPart(head, null);
    }

    private ListNode sortPart(ListNode start, ListNode end){
        if(start == null)return null;
        if(start == end)return start; 

        ListNode l=start, r=start, p=start.next;

        while(p!= null && p!=end){
            if(p.val < start.val){ // current node less than start node
                r.next = p.next;
                p.next = l;
                l = p; // set current node as leftmost
                p = start.next; // go to next node
            }else{ // current node no less more start node
                r = p; // set current node as rightmost and go to next node
                p = p.next; 
            }
        }

        // recursively sort left part and right part
        sortPart(l,start);
        sortPart(start.next, r);

        return l;
    }
}
```

Comment: What algorithm do you use? Is it quick sort?

Comment: On first glance this does not seem to work. Better comment what the algorithm wants to achieve with every step (=explain). Naming as `leftMost` might help too, making some current comments superfluous.

Comment: The way you are manipulating pointers in the partitioning is very far from correct.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805936/optimal-quicksort-for-single-linked-list .

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it is quick sort, and I need to improve the implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bug is probably that a quicksort on an already sorted list is `O(n*n)`.  One practical solution is random selection of the pivot.  The standard online reservoir sampling algorithm solves that.

However that still might not be good enough.  Quicksort will create a callstack with `O(log(n))` calls which therefore takes `O(log(n))` space.  If they set up good enough tests, they should be able to verify that you've gone over.

For a real solution, see http://comjnl.oxfordjournals.org/content/35/6/643.full.pdf.

Given how many people have passed this problem, I suspect that they do not accurately catch the difference between `O(log(n))` space and `O(1)` space.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really points out where I didn't considered.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you went for quick sort...its worst case is O(n * n)....what you were looking for was 
Heap sort
 O(n+n*log(n)) eqiv. to O(nlog(n))  and with space complexity of O(1)