# Haskell Quick Sort implementation (how to obtain the best performance?)

Tags: algorithm, performance, haskell, functional-programming, quicksort

I am currently reading about functional data structures and algorithms and I tried different quick sort implementations. I noticed, however, that there is a lot of variation in their performances.

Here are some selected ones that I want to discuss (all the programs have been compiled (`ghc program.hs`) for test (the time in parentheses is the one obtained with the optimization `-O` flag), and the list to be sorted was the (worst case already sorted (which implies that the time taken is in **O**(n^2))) [1 .. 20000] list):

```
qs1 []             = []
qs1 (pivot : rest) = qs1 lower ++ [pivot] ++ qs1 upper  where
  lower = [ x | x <- rest, x <= pivot ]
  upper = [ x | x <- rest, x >  pivot ]
```

This is the classic sort we see when we learn the language. Here, the `rest` list is traversed twice to filter first the elements less or equal than the pivot, then the elements greater than the pivot. The time taken was 6.45 (4.42) sec.

```
qs2 []             = []
qs2 (pivot : rest) = qs2 lower ++ [pivot] ++ qs2 upper  where
  (lower, upper) = foldr
    (\x (l, u) -> if x <= pivot then (x : l, u) else (l, x : u))
    ([], [])
    rest
```

I was surprised by this one. It is the same as above, except that it only traverses the `rest` list once. It did worse than the first with a total of 8.11 (2.95) sec. I tried the `partition` function from Data.List library, but it only did worse (much worse), with a catastrophic 10.99 (9.99) sec. I checked the implementation, and yet it is almost the same as my lambda function, although it relies on an utility function:

```
partition               :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a],[a])
partition p xs = foldr (select p) ([],[]) xs

select :: (a -> Bool) -> a -> ([a], [a]) -> ([a], [a])
select p x ~(ts,fs) | p x       = (x:ts,fs)
                    | otherwise = (ts, x:fs)
```

(Taken from https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/Data.OldList.html#partition).

```
qs3 []             s = s
qs3 (pivot : rest) s = qs3 lower (pivot : (qs3 upper s))  where
    lower = [ x | x <- rest, x <= pivot ]
    upper = [ x | x <- rest, x >  pivot ]
```

In this one, there are 2 novelties. Fist, the removal of append `++` in favour of cons `:`. Second, it is a tail recursion function, so it should (in principle) be faster. However, it is merely better than the first one, with a time of 6.42 (4.44) sec. In fact, due to variation from an execution to the other, it probably is the same.

```
qs4 []             s = s
qs4 (pivot : rest) s = qs4 lower (pivot : (qs4 upper s))  where
  (lower, upper) = foldr
    (\x (l, u) -> if x <= pivot then (x : l, u) else (l, x : u))
    ([], [])
    rest
```

Again, this is the same as above, except that I replaced the 2 list traversal by a `foldr`, and again, the time taken is increased: 8.02 (2.95) sec.

```
split pivot [] lower upper s = qs5 lower (pivot : qs5 upper s)
split pivot (h : t) lower upper s
     | h <= pivot = split pivot t (h : lower) upper s
     | otherwise  = split pivot t lower (h : upper) s

qs5 []             s = s
qs5 (pivot : rest) s = split pivot rest [] [] s
```

This one is the fastest. I recorded a stunning time of 2.82 (1.92) sec, which is almost 4 times faster than the “slowest”. It bounces between 2 functions that calls each other. `split` is a recursive function that separates the elements of the `rest` list sent by the `qs5` functions, which it returns to when it is done partitioning.

---

Conclusion: What the hell is going on here? I am puzzled by all the hidden subtleties done during the compilation that makes my expectations concerning the performance of the program go wrong. I humbly thank anyone who could help me untangle the pieces of this jigsaw by pointing out what is going on under the hood.

Comment: To begin: how you are measuring those times? Ideally, one should use a benchmark library like `criterion`. Alternatively, you can compile your code with optimization on and run the code a few times. GHCi, instead, should never be used to measure performance since it skips many optimizations so to reload code faster.

Comment: I compiled all the programs with `ghc program.hs` and timed them with time (i.e. `time ./program`. I ran the programs several times and the difference was never significative (+/- 0.05 sec). I edited the original post to also include times with the `-O` flag, which changes drastically the time taken by each, but still, I would like to know why it goes from one to the other.

Comment: Nice. It's not always easy to reason about performance in Haskell, because of its laziness. `qs4` and `qs5` use a known technique to avoid the slow `++`, using "difference lists" (you can search for that). On top, `qs5` avoids passing pairs in favour of multiple arguments, which could be faster (if the deforestation optimization does not kick in). You could also try `qs4` with ``\x (l, u) -> l `seq` u `seq` if .....`` to see if that changes something, but it's only a wild guess.

Comment: @PhilipGaudreau, be sure to use `-O2`.

Comment: Don't use lists, or you will never get the best performance for quicksort. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19752983/is-it-possible-to-speed-up-a-quicksort-with-par-in-haskell/55885118#55885118