# Unfold returning the last state of the accumulator

Tags: haskell, pointfree, unfold

The `unfold` function in Haskell is very handy to create lists. Its definition is:

```
unfold :: (b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> [a]
```

But I would like to get the last value of the accumulator used. A possible implementation is:

```
unfoldRest :: (b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> ([a], b)
unfoldRest fct ini = go fct ini []
  where
    go f s acc =
      case f s of
        Nothing -> (acc, s)
        Just (a, b) -> go f b (acc ++ [a])
```

But I was wondering if there wasn't a way to do it with existing functions. In the end this:

```
countDown 0 = Nothing
countDown n = Just (n, n-1)
unfoldRest countDown 10
```

will return:

```
([10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1],0)
```

Because the iteration stopped when the accumulator value reached `0`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import Data.List

unfoldr' :: (b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> [(a, b)]
unfoldr' f = unfoldr (fmap (\(a, b) -> ((a, b), b)) . f)
```

will give you *all* the states of the accumulator.  Then you can choose to look at whichever you want, including the last.

Comment: Ok, that does mean I will need to post-process the list, but it seems to be the better solution!

Comment: then implementing `unfoldRest` is non-trivial: `unfoldRest f z = maybe ([],z) (map fst *** last) (listToMaybe $ unfoldr' f z)` is likely to have a space leak.

Comment: That doesn't typecheck.

Comment: right, I misused `listToMaybe`. What I meant was `unfoldRest f z = list ([],z) (map fst &&& (last . map snd)) (unfoldr' f z)` where `list z f [] = z; list z f xs = f xs`.

Comment: I don't see why that's subject to *more* space leaks than PierreBdR's version.  In both cases you have to have evaluated the whole list to get the final state.

Comment: @TomEllis why compare with the OP version? I didn't. The point is that simple `x = (map fst &&& last . map snd) xs` is a [classic Bird's space leak](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7859298/849891) - while `fst x` gets consumed the whole list `xs` is held on to by `snd x` (i.e. there's two independent traversals of `xs` so it's kept in memory whole). The correct `foldr ...` implementation which fuses the two operations is non-trivial (simple enough, just not trivial). duplode's version doesn't have this problem. yours is more general, at a cost.

Answer (score 3):

This is not much of an answer (Tom Ellis' better covers the "a way to do it with existing functions" part), but it is worth it taking a second look at your original solution. Since you are using `(++)` to append single elements repeatedly, it takes quadratic time with respect to the length of the generated list. You can avoid that by dropping the helper function and building the list directly with `(:)`:

```
unfoldRest' :: (b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> ([a], b)
unfoldRest' f s = case f s of
    Nothing -> ([], s)
    Just (a, b) -> (\ ~(xs, y) -> (a : xs, y)) $ unfoldRest' f b
```

The lazy pattern match (`~(xs, y)` in the lambda) is important; it allows you to look at the first elements of the list without having to calculate the final state, and therefore to do something useful with infinite lists (in any case, Tom Ellis' solution is better for infinite lists, as you can see the not only the generated values but also state after any arbitrary segment). As Will Ness points out, you may find the right hand side of the `Just` case more natural to write using a `let` binding, as in `let (xs, y) = unfoldRest' f b in (a : xs, y)`.

As you tagged the question with "pointfree", it is worth it mentioning that you can reduce quite a lot the amount of points by using `maybe` and the `Control.Arrow` combinators:

```
import Control.Arrow ((***), first, app)

unfoldRest'' f s =
    maybe ([], s) (app . (first . (:) *** unfoldRest'' f)) $ f s
```

Whether you want to go that far is a matter of taste. The laziness issue is dealt with correctly, as the implementation of `(***)` for functions uses a lazy pattern match.

Comment: You can write `uncurry ($)` as `app` from Control.Arrow.

Comment: @Toxaris That's a nice touch. Answer updated, thank you.

Comment: your solution has an edge over Tom's, though - see [my comment there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23548516/unfold-returning-the-last-state-of-the-accumulator/23550225#comment36161833_23548810). --- about your first variant: you could use explicit `let` there, as `let` bindings are lazy.

Answer (score 1):

I've grappled with this problem before - one of ways to solve it is by using the [State monad](https://wiki.haskell.org/State_Monad).

In simple terms, they deal with functions on the form `s -> (d, s)`. Intuitively, `s` is the type of the state that may change during a computation.

The first thing to note is that `s -> Maybe (d, s)` doesn't have the form `s -> (d, s)`: the former is a tuple of things, while the latter is a `Maybe`, we need a function on the type `s -> (Maybe d, s)`, if the function returns `None`, the modified function will return the previous state. One possible implementation of this adapter is:

```
keepFailure :: (s -> Maybe (d, s)) -> (s -> (Maybe d, s))
keepFailure f s = maybe (Nothing, s) (first Just) (f s)
```

Remember to `import Data.Bifunctor` because of the `first` function
There's a function that converts from `s -> (d, s)` to `State s d` called `state`, and
`runState` to convert it back. Now we implement the function which is will try exhausting the state of all possible values:

```
stateUnfoldr :: State s (Maybe d) -> State s [d]
stateUnfoldr f = do
  mx <- f
  case mx of
    Just x -> do
      xs <- stateUnfoldr f
      return $ x:xs
    Nothing -> return []
```

In simple terms, `mx <- f` works like "apply `f` to the input, update the state, get assign the return value to `mx`"
Then, we can piece everything together:

```
fStateUnfoldr :: (s -> Maybe (d, s)) -> (s -> ([d], s))
fStateUnfoldr f = runState $ stateUnfoldr $ state . keepFailure $ f
```

Remember to `import Control.Monad.State`

`state . keepFailure` adapts `f` into a `State s (Maybe d)` Monad, then `stateUnfoldr` unfolds to a `State s [d]`, then `runState` turns it back to a function.

We can also use the `execState` or `evalState` instead of `runState` if you want just the state or just the list.