# Explanation of quicksort in APL

Tags: quicksort, in-place, apl, dyalog

I am attempting to understand the classic quicksort in APL:

```
Q←{1≥≢⍵:⍵ ⋄ S←{⍺⌿⍨⍺ ⍺⍺ ⍵} ⋄ ⍵((∇<S)⍪=S⍪(∇>S))⍵⌷⍨?≢⍵}
```

There are some things I don't understand, and some stylistic choices that bother me, so I'm going to list all of them out. I hope someone can explain them to me.

1. I understand that inside a `{ }` defn, `⍺` is the left argument, and `⍵` is the right argument. What is  `⍺⍺` in `S←{⍺⌿⍨⍺ ⍺⍺ ⍵}`? Similarly, is there an `⍵⍵`? Does the `⍺` inside the `S` refer to the *left argument of `S`* or the *left argument of `Q`*?

My guess is that `⍺` inside the `S` refers to the left argument of `S`. The `⍺⍺` refers to the `⍺` of the *enclosing function* (ie, the `⍺` of Q).

2. Why the copious use of commute (`⍨`)? Is the code not far clearer written as:

```
Q←{1≥≢⍵:⍵ ⋄ S←{(⍺ ⍺⍺ ⍵)⌿⍺} ⋄ ⍵((∇<S)⍪=S⍪(∇>S))⍵[?≢⍵]}
```

The only use I can think of using commute is to reduce the use of brackets `()` and `[]`, but that hardly seems worth the loss in legibility. Am I missing something of the "APL way" here?

3. This is not actually performing quicksort, is it? Quicksort is defined as being *in-place*. However, my understanding of the APL semantics is that this piece of code in fact *builds new arrays* on the recursive sub-calls, and the concatenates them using `⍪`. Indeed, this is the [same criticism that is levelled at Haskell's quicksort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7718269/5305365). Is there something I am missing in the APL semantics that informs that this operation is done "in-place"? Do note that I am not interested in "sufficiently smart compiler" arguments, since array analysis is fundamentally challenging. If the APL compiler *does actually turn this into an in-place algorithm*, I would greatly value details on how it manages to perform this analysis --- that's quite an accomplishment!
4. Why the use of `≢⍵` to find the dimension size? Why not `⍴⍵`? In general, I find that people use `≢` over `⍴` to query for the size along the outermost dimension, *even when the only case where the function work is in 1D*. Again, I presume there is something in the APL way that I am missing.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. I understand that inside a `{ }` defn, `⍺` is the left argument, and `⍵` is the right argument. What is `⍺⍺` in `S←{⍺⌿⍨⍺ ⍺⍺ ⍵}`? Similarly, is there an `⍵⍵`?

`S←{⍺⌿⍨⍺ ⍺⍺ ⍵}` is called a *dop*. Similar to a *dfn* being a user-defined function, *dop* is a user-defined operator which behaves like `¨`, `⍨`, or `∘`.

Summary of its semantics:

- If a dop mentions only `⍺⍺` (not `⍵⍵`), it becomes a monadic operator, which you can use as `x (m S) y`.
- If a dop mentions `⍵⍵`, it becomes a dyadic operator, which you can use as `x (m S n) y`.
- In both cases, `⍺⍺` (which will have the value of `m`) and `⍵⍵` (which will have that of `n`) can be an array or a function.
- You can also decide to not use `⍺` in the dop's body, in which case you can call it as either `(m S) y` or `(m S n) y`, omitting the left *argument*.
- `m` is called the *left operand*, and `n` is the *right operand*. These are different things from a *left argument* (`x`) and *right argument* (`y`).

In your example, `S` mentions only `⍺⍺`, so it is called as `x (m S) y`. If you call `S` like `1 2 3 >S 2`, it will evaluate to `1 2 3⌿⍨1 2 3 > 2`, which will be a single 3.

> Does the `⍺` inside the `S` refer to the left argument of `S` or the left argument of `Q`?

Inside the body of `S`, everything made of `⍺` and `⍵` characters refers to the argument/operand of `S`. The original arguments of `Q` are invisible (unless they are assigned to a variable first, in which case they are visible as the variable name).

> 2. Why the copious use of commute (`⍨`)?

I believe it is mostly a stylistic choice. I also prefer to write parenthesized code instead of using it in production code, except when the usage is easily recognizable as an APL idiom. I do write e.g. `3÷⍨whatever` instead of `(whatever)÷3` for division by constant.

> 3. This is not actually performing quicksort, is it?

You're correct. As you mentioned already, Quicksort is designed to run in-place to truly become *Quick* (TM). APL can do memory pre-allocation and array sharing to reduce some of the memory copy and allocation, but at least some copies are unavoidable when the three sub-arrays (having elements less than / equal to / greater than the pivot) are created and later concatenated.

One thing to note is that, unlike Haskell, APL does have in-place assignment which looks like `x[i]←v`. If one were to implement Quicksort properly in APL, one would have to code like one would code in C (passing indices to recursive calls and such).

> 4. Why the use of `≢⍵` to find the dimension size? Why not `⍴⍵`?

`≢` is called "tally" while `⍴` is called "shape". `≢` always returns a scalar value, while `⍴` returns a vector (it would be a length one vector if given a vector argument). While a scalar and a length-one vector behave the same in most scenarios, they *are* different things, e.g. `1≡,1` is false.

I believe it's a good habit to differentiate the two, favoring a scalar over a length-one vector whenever possible. One notable exception is when you need an explicitly enclosed array (a scalar can't be enclosed).