# Is it possible to implement a general in-place quicksort in haskell?

Tags: haskell, quicksort

The term *general* (contrary to *specialized*) in the question means the function can sort the items as long as they are of a type that is an instance of `Ord`.

Consider one of the most famous haskell ads

```
quicksort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
quicksort []     = []
quicksort (p:xs) = (quicksort lesser) ++ [p] ++ (quicksort greater)
    where
        lesser  = filter (< p) xs
        greater = filter (>= p) xs
```

The above implementation is not in-place.
 
I was trying to write an in-place version. 
It's easy to make quicksort in-place. Usually, we just need a mutable array and I chose `Foreign.Marshal.Array`.
My implementation is in-place and runs very well, but I am not satisfied with its type signature

```
(Ord a, Storable a) => [a] -> IO [a]
```

To be more precise, the type constraint `Storable a` annoyed me.

Obviously, if we want to sort items, `Ord` constraint is needed, while `Storable` is unnecessary.
In contrast, the type signatures of the classic quicksort or `sort` in `Data.List`, is `Ord a => [a] -> [a]`. The constraint is just `Ord`.

I didn't find a way to get rid of the additional constraint.

I searched Stackoverflow, and found some questions about in-place quicksort in haskell, e.g.
 
[How do you do an in-place quicksort in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268156/how-do-you-do-an-in-place-quicksort-in-haskell)
[Why is the minimalist, example Haskell quicksort not a "true" quicksort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717691/why-is-the-minimalist-example-haskell-quicksort-not-a-true-quicksort)

Unfortunately, their major concern is just in-place. All of the in-place quicksort examples given there have additional type constraints as well.
For example, [`iqsort` given by klapaucius](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7833043/779412)  has the type signature

```
iqsort :: (Vector v a, Ord a) => v a -> v a
```

Does anyone know how to implement an in-place quicksort haskell function with type signature `Ord a => [a] -> [a]`?
I know how to make an in-place quicksort, but I don't know how to make it *general*.

Comment: isn't the intention of Haskell (i mean being _pure_ functional language) against the in-place sort of things (as the in-place modifications are kind of the side-effects of functions, it is not pure function if it modify arguments)

Comment: In place and `Ord a => [a] -> [a]` don't make sense together. Haskell lists simply don't do in-place. You're going to need to use IO or ST or State for in-place, because in-place implies mutability. Notice that the instances of [`Vector v a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.10.0.1/doc/html/Data-Vector-Generic.html) are choc-full of fixed-size types that are easy to unbox.

Comment: @VB9-UANIC It's fine to have mutations hidden under pure interface if user cannot possibly detect them. See `ST` monad for example.

Comment: Why `Foreign`? What's wrong with `IOArray` and `STArray`?

Comment: As an example of what others are talking about, see my `vsort` function in [this previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357663/python-faster-than-compiled-haskell/10360424#10360424).

Comment: can you please explain what exactly to be in-place mean? if I take an array (not a dictionary), does it matter if a sorting algorithm is in-place or not?

Comment: As all the answers indicate: it is possible, but in general not actually good for performance. Quicksort is O(n^2) worst-case and O(n.log n) best-case. The algorithm used by `sort` in `Data.List` is O(n.log n) worst-case and O(n) best-case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible. (Although in Haskell you want to use this kind of imperative algorithms only in cases where you *really* need top performance.)

I know of 2 such algorithms:

- [sort](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector-algorithms/0.3.2/doc/html/Data-Vector-Algorithms-Intro.html#v%3asort) from *vector-algorithms*.
- [qsort](https://github.com/ppetr/marray-sort/blob/master/src/Data/Array/MArray/Sort/Introsort.hs) (or introsort) from [marray-sort](https://github.com/ppetr/marray-sort), which I haven't released to Hackage yet. (Let me know if you need it.) It works on [mutable arrays](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Arrays#Mutable_IO_arrays_.28module_Data.Array.IO.29).

([Introsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort) is basically refined quicksort that has  *O(n log n)* worst case complexity.)

I'm not sure about `MVector`, but for `MArray`s, you don't have to worry about the additional constraints `MArray a e m`. They're there to make the type *more general*, not less. Signatures like

```
qsort :: (MArray a e m, Ord e) => a Int e -> m ()
```

allow to use the same algorithm for different array representations. For some data types, you can have specialized arrays of that type which are faster and more compact than generic arrays. For example, if you want to sort 8-bit integers, there is a specialized instance `MArray IOUArray Int8 IO` for [unboxed arrays](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Arrays#Unboxed_arrays). And a specialization of `qsort` for this kind of arrays just using polymorphism is

```
qsort :: IOUArray Int Int8 -> IO ()
```

But you also have instance `MArray IOArray e IO` that works arbitrary `e`. By using `qsort` with `IOArray`, you get a specialization without constraints on `e`:

```
qsort :: (Ord e) => IOArray Int e -> IO ()
```

Furthermore, if you use [`STArray`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/array/latest/doc/html/Data-Array-ST.html)s and the [`ST`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Monad-ST.html) monad, you can sort an array in-place using the same function, and get the result later  as a pure value, without `IO`.

Comment: Ah! `MArray IOArray e IO`, how can I missed that? I thought all of them were specializations. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

`iqsort` actually looks fully general to me. If you look at the Data.Vector.Generic haddocks, you in fact can use that interface for *any* `a`! The difference is that the function as given is *more* generic, because it allows you to choose an *unboxed* vector, which of course only works over *some* `a`.

Here's the link: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.10.0.1/doc/html/Data-Vector-Generic.html

So if you pick your V to be boxed, the vector constraint goes away.

Comment: Said another way: the `Ord a` constraint is necessary to generalize to "any" `a`, while the `Vector v a` constraint is necessary to generalize to "any" vector. By specializing to a particular vector type, you eliminate the `Vector v a` constraint, just as by specializing to a particular `a` type, you eliminate the `Ord a` constraint.

Comment: @DanBurton My understanding is: `Vector v a` is a constrait to `a`. `[a]` is also a constraint to 'a' and is stronger than `Vector v a`. Namely, all `a` subject to `[a]` can be regarded as some `Vector v a`. `Vector [] a` is not yet implemented, but it is trivial to add. Is that correct?

Comment: That makes no sense. `Vector v a` is a typeclass constraint. `[a]` is a type that is polymorphic in `a`, not a constraint. You don't want to sort a *list* inplace. [a] is a list of a, which is a singly-linked-list. You want to use `MVector ST a`, which is a mutable vector of `a` in the ST monad.

Comment: I know where my mistake is. `quicksort` with type signature `Ord a => [a] -> [a]` is not the same as `quicksort` can sort the items as long as they are of a type that is an instance of `Ord`. Actually `iqsort` given by klapaucius is a valid general in-place quicksort.