# Sorting large collection with haskell

Tags: haskell

I have gigabytes of integers and I want to sort them. How this may be done in haskell without creating a copy of the initial list every iteration?

Comment: What "iteration"s are you referring to?

Comment: Relevant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting

Comment: You may want to use mutable vectors an in-place sort. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268156/how-do-you-do-an-in-place-quicksort-in-haskell

Comment: is this a trick question from some job interview - from a time when ints where small, so the intended answer was something with bucketsort?

Comment: I'd use an online sorting algorithm such as insertion sort and push stuff through it using conduit. I think that with a little thinking I could manage to merge sort the chunks that conduit would provide to a sink.

Answer (score 0):

The standard mergesort algorithm in Haskell already doesn't create a copy of the whole list -- it just breaks down the list into chunks and merges those.

The `vector-algorithms` package (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-algorithms) also provides a number of common and efficient in-place sort algorithms.